# What python library do you recommend for creating a push notification server in 2018?

Tags: library, python, notification

I am writing a forum component for a larger website and a I would like to include notifications when a new post or message has arrived. Is using the Twisted libraries still a great choice for something like this these days? This is for a site that has close to 500k hits per month.

Comment: Jaigus, if the answer solves your question, please don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **[Pulsus](https://github.com/pennersr/pulsus)**.

It's simple, well documented and, in the author's words: running rock solid in production for several years now.

Comment: It handles Apple APNS, and Google GCM